The fisher and the fish
A fisher is somewhere on the edge of a rectangle-shaped lake, and a fish is somewhere inside of it. The lake measures $a\times b$. What is the probability that the fisher is closer to the center than the fish is? (Assume that the probability distributions of the fisher and fish are both uniform.)
I've been thinking a lot about variations of the above question recently. (I invented the question.) For a square lake (so $a=b$), the probability is $\frac{1-\ln2}3 \approx 0.10228$. For a triangular lake it's $\frac{3-2\ln2}9 \approx 0.17930$. In general, for a regular $n$-gon, it's  $\frac13-\frac{\ln(t^2+1)}{3t^2}$ where $t:=\tan(\frac\pi n)$. (Proof of these results omitted. It's some integrals; they're doable with pencil and paper with the right substitutions.)
The probability for regular $n$-gons is shown below in blue. Interestingly, this is approximately $\frac{\pi^2}{6n^2}$ for large $n$ (shown in red).

I figure once all the above is known, it's only natural to consider other shapes. I'm interested in a variety of cases (cube lake? square lake but off-center?), but for the sake of definiteness I figure I'll ask about the rectangle case first.
Here are some thoughts. We can divide the rectangle into four sections via the diagonals. I figure it's relatively easy to find the probability in the case where the fisher and fish are in the same (or opposite) sections, using the formula I found for regular polygons (letting $t$ be $a/b$ or $b/a$). The issue is the case where they're in adjacent sections; I'm not sure what the best setup is then.

Apparently there's a tag called fisher-information, lol

@AkivaWeinberger Sure, but it is a different Fisher. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher)

I figured! @Xander

Can you share the work for one of these cases? Reason being that I would have approached this by finding the CDF of Man and for Fish, then look at the probability that M < F. Whereas you seem to indicate that (at least) for the rectangle, you condition on which section they appear in.

Let $O$ be the center of the rectangle and $F$ the position of the fisher. If $c$ is the circle of center $O$ and radius $OF$, then the probability that the fisher is closer to $O$ than the fish is the ratio between the area of the region inside the rectangle but outside $c$, divided by the area of the rectangle. Integrating that over the various positions of the fisher will give the required probability.
Because of the symmetries of the rectangle, we can consider just the upper-right quadrant of the rectangle. Let's start with the case when $F$ lies on the upper side $AB$ of the quadrant, and $OF<AB$ (see figure below). I'll suppose WLOG that $AB\ge BC$, that is $a\ge b$.
Setting $x=AF$, $AB=a/2$, $BC=b/2$ the above condition entails $0\le x\le\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)/4}$. The probability that the fisher is closer to $O$ than the fish is then:
$$
p_1(x)={4\over ab}\left(
{ab\over4}-{bx\over4}-{b^2+4x^2\over8}\arctan{b\over2x}
\right)
$$
which must then be integrated over $x$:
$$
P_1={2\over a+b}\int_0^\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)/4}p_1(x)\,dx.
$$

Let's consider then the case when $\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)/4}\le x\le a/2$ (see figure below). The probability in this case is
$$
p_2(x)={4\over ab}\left(
{ab\over4}-{bx\over4}-{a\over8}\sqrt{4x^2-a^2+b^2}
-{b^2+4x^2\over8}\Bigg(\arctan{b\over2x}-\arctan{\sqrt{4x^2-a^2+b^2}\over a}\Bigg)
\right)
$$
which must then be integrated over $x$:
$$
P_2={2\over a+b}\int_\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)/4}^{a/2}p_2(x)\,dx.
$$
Finally, we must consider the case when the fisher is at $F'$ on $BC$. In that case we can set $CF'=y=\sqrt{x^2+b^2/4-a^2/4}$: the formula for the probability $p_3(y)$ is the same as $p_2(x)$ written above, with the substitution: $x=\sqrt{y^2+a^2/4-b^2/4}$:
$$
p_3(y)={4\over ab}\left(
{ab\over4}-{ay\over4}-{b\over8}\sqrt{4y^2+a^2-b^2}
-{a^2+4y^2\over8}\Bigg(\arctan{b\over2\sqrt{y^2+a^2/4-b^2/4}}-\arctan{2y\over a}\Bigg)
\right)
$$
Integrating that we get the last piece:
$$
P_3={2\over a+b}\int_0^{b/2} p_3(y)\,dy.
$$

The total probability is given by $P=P_1+P_2+P_3$. It can be conveniently expressed as a function of the aspect-ratio $r=b/a$. Computing the above integrals with Mathematica I obtained:
$$
P(r)=
\frac{1}{3}
+\frac{ r^2}{3  (r+1)} \ln (r)
-\frac{ (1-r)^2}{4 r } \ln (1-r)
- \frac{(r+1)^2}{12 r} \ln (r+1)
$$
One can check that
$$
\lim_{r\to1^-}P(r)={1-\ln2\over3}\approx 0.10228,
$$
thus recovering the result for a square. Here's a plot of $P(r)$:

